# JEST compatibility for Angular-4

Tags: angular, jestjs

I am working on angular project with version-4 & as per the requirement need to implement JEST framework for Unit testing, I have tried with latest version of JEST:29.3.1 but getting below error:

> ERROR : while running : ng run test
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at isAfterVersion
> \node_modules\jest-preset-angular\build\ngtsc\ts compatibility\src\ts_cross_version_utils.js:87:67) at Object.
> \node_modules\jest-preset-angular\build\ngtsc\ts_compatibility\src\ts_cross_version_utils.js:13:24)
> at Module. compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)

Tried with lower version of JEST as well but getting same error.

package.json

```
dependencies": {
    "@angular/aninations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0"
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compile": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.8",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":"4.8.8",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.8",
    "bootstrap": "3.5.7",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "Jest": "29.3.1",
    "jest-preset-anguler: 12.2.3"
}
```

Comment: You should use a jest-preset-anguler version that is compatible with Angular 4

Comment: thank you! Alexander, could you suggest the version I have tried with **jest @ ^20.0.0**.

Comment: Lowest is  jest-preset-angular 5 with Jest 22. If that does not work, upgrade Angular because v4 is ancient